# Is there a way to trigger a Python function with BeautifulSoup from a post posted on TheHackerNews?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

web_scrape = 'https://thehackernews.com/'

uClient = uReq(web_scrape)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
```

Right now, I have this code. I don't want to go any further without writing the function I mentioned earlier in the title. I want to write a function that runs whenever a post is posted on TheHackerNews. (Using web scraping to get to the post's information I am assuming.) I have no clue how to do this, can anybody help me??

Comment: Nope. You can scrape their rss feed( I am sure they may provide this). Or you can run your scraper every 5 mins or else

Comment: How would I get the certain container that the post is in everytime, would it not be different?

Comment: It would be same all the time.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not getting this, how- and where- would I find the posts??

Comment: you have to learn web scrapping course. learn about xpaths css selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feedparser` allows you to to check the [last-modified headers](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/http-etag.html#using-last-modified-headers-to-reduce-bandwidth) of the rss feed to check for new messages. It will only return messages if new messages have been posted since the last request. This allows for a low-bandwith solution without any scraping.

```
import feedparser
import time

d = feedparser.parse('https://feeds.feedburner.com/TheHackersNews')
last_modified = d.modified

while True:
    d2 = feedparser.parse('https://feeds.feedburner.com/TheHackersNews', modified=last_modified)

    if d2.status == 304:
        print('no new messages')
    elif d2.status == 200:
        last_modified = d2.modified
        print('new messages')
        # trigger function here

    time.sleep(300) #sleep for 5 mins
```

Comment: Ok, I believe this works, but how would I get the information on the post with web scraping?

Comment: The data of the posts can be found in `d['entries']` or `d2['entries']`, the latter only when `d2.status == 200`. Run `print(d['entries'])` to see what the data structure looks like.

Comment: Is there any way to also get the link of the post?

Comment: Yes , they can be found under `d['entries'][i]['feedburner_origlink']`. Note that `d['entries']` is a list of article data, so you'd have to loop it to get the links.

Comment: Wait, what is the " i " ?

Comment: That is the key of the item in the list. You have to fill in a number there. You can get all links with `[i['feedburner_origlink'] for i in d['entries']]`